# How to use Pear with xampp?

Tags: xampp, pear

How do i include Pear's QuickForm into a php file if Pear is already installed in xampp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran go-pear.bat from the command line, and it ran a setup program to configure my system for PEAR.

When it was finished I was left with some new folders and a pear.bat file. I tested it with "pear install -f Text_CAPTCHA" and everything seemed to work.

Comment: Sure but what i want to know is after its installed how do you include a component such as QuickForm into a php file so i can use it?

Comment: Did you try: require_once "HTML/QuickForm.php";?

Comment: http://www.unitedforums.co.uk/vb/website-development-scripting/8485-how-use-pear-packages.html