# QuickForm & Pear in xampp?

Tags: xampp, pear

Im running xampp and i see the Pear folders in the php subdirectory. I have the html_quickform folder but i dont know where to place it?

Do i place it in the first Pear folders or the next Pear folders? I created a HTML folder on the first Pear folder to place it in but im getting this error:

```
**index.php**
require_once('HTML/QuickForm/QuickForm.php');
```

.

```
Warning: require_once(HTML/Common.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\projects\xampp\php\PEAR\HTML\QuickForm\QuickForm.php on line 33

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'HTML/Common.php' (include_path='C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\projects\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\projects\xampp\php\PEAR\HTML\QuickForm\QuickForm.php on line 33
```

However the warning says i need html/common.php but there's no such thing in the Pear installation. THe only place i see common.php is in the second Pear folder but it is in the root not a HTML folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010066/how-to-use-pear-with-xampp/4010076#4010076), you need to follow the instructions to install PEAR. And then you'll have a `pear.bat` which you need to run from the *prompt*.

In a nutshell:

```
c:\...\pear\go-pear.bat
```

It's better to use the installer to set it up:

```
pear(.bat) install html_quickform
```

(`.bat` if it's windows.)

It'll create the following structure:

```
C:\...\pear\HTML\QuickForm.php
C:\...\pear\HTML\QuickForm\...
etc. pp.
```

Doublecheck in your `php.ini` that `C:\...\pear` is in your `include_path`.

Then:

```
<?php
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm.php';
```

Comment: there is no pear.bat in xampp

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Till's instructions i was able to do it(Windows)
For Windows users If you installed xampp under C:\,

1. Go to `C:\xampp\php` (type it on the command prompt, under this folder there is the pear.bat file)
2. Execute `pear.bat` by the following line `pear.bat install html_quickform` it will install the necessary folders
3. It will create the HTML folder that contains the `QuickForm.php` file .You can see it by checking under `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\HTML`
4. In the program you call it by simply doing:

   ```
   require_once("HTML/QuickForm.php");

   $form = new HTML_QuickForm(); // with form being the QuickForm() object.
   ```